# Create a HTML table without a fixed layout, with max-width set, and with rows that don't wrap but have overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here's the starter code:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 300px;
}

td:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*Further explanation:*

I want to create a table that will calculate its columns' widths on its own, but have some max width. The catch is I can't have the text inside my **td** wrap, but it's fine if it's hidden with overflow property.

(If you haven't run the code: the table basically ignores the max-width)

Can this be done?

Comment: I have added the code. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. Hope it will work for you. If any changes please let me know.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;   // This can be set to whatever.
}

td div {
  max-height: 1.1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: transparent;
}

td div::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div title="Hello">Hello</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div title="-">-</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div title="This is a super long cell. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The five boxing wizards jump quickly.">
        This is a super long cell. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The five boxing wizards jump quickly.
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div title="World">World</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but as I have said I don't want my text content to wrap in the table (library I am using doesn't like wrapping)

Comment: Table again goes over 300px. It clips the td elements at 300px, but that  doesn't help me.

Comment: @SavoPejović What do you want actually? Can you just give me briefly?

Comment: @SavoPejović. I made changes. Please check and let me know.

Comment: I want a table with a fixed width, e.g. 300px, but I don't want its columns to have a fixed width, that is let it figure it out on its own, based on the width of the **td** content. Since I also don't want the content to wrap into multiple lines, and there must be some sort of cropping happening if I want my table to fit into predefined max-width, I am wondering can this be achieved using overflow/text-overflowproperties

Comment: @SavoPejović Hey I have updated the code. Please check. If any changes please let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205123/discussion-between-revti-shah-and-savo-pejovic).

Comment: This solution is a little complex, but since you can't control the behaviour of **td** a lot, this is fine. Thanks